# Алгоритм hypot для 3 и более элементов

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Существует ли аналог алгоритма `std::hypot()` для вектора с 3+ элементами в стандартной библиотеке? Если нет, то можно предложить подобный по функционалу алгоритм?

Comment: А чем не нравится корень из суммы квадратов?

Comment: @MBo переполнением

Comment: @PavelGridin при больших значениях x и y сумма их квадратов теряет точность

Comment: стёрлось сообщение, понятно, т. е. double не хватает

Comment: Может попробовать hypot из Intel IPP. Из описания: function flavor ippsHypot_64f_A53 guarantees 53 correctly rounded bits of significand, including the implied bit, with the maximum guaranteed error within 1 ulp

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-hypot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз могут возникнуть проблемы с переполнением, то можно использовать ту же технику, что и в `hypot`:

Выбирается максимальное по модулю значение из вектор

```
AMax = Max(Abs(V[i]))
```

Вычисляется сумма квадратов нормированных на этот максимум компонентов

```
for all:
   nv = V[i] / AMax
   sum += nv * nv
```

Извлекается корень и возвращается нужный порядок

```
  hyp = AMax * Sqrt(sum)
```

*Можно также отсортировать компоненты и суммировать с минимальных по модулю либо использовать алгоритм Кэхэна.*